# How to access an project on CakePhP

Tags: cakephp

I have others project that I access like this : `localhost/myProject/` and works... But recently I got another project from Assembla and I'm trying to access like this : `localhost/otherProject` and not works... Images to understand :
[image]

On the root folder the project is there :
[image]

What I'm missing to open the project successfully ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a simple problem with your htaccess

Comment: The htaccess it's ok... same of the other project... I checked !

Comment: The convention of caKephp with underscore is sometimes messy try to rename

Comment: But in another computer is working fine ! Just on mine that doesn't work !

Answer (score 0):

the server have returned an http code 500 - Internal Server Error
-> you need to check the Apache error log (there is usually an item for it in the WampServer menu, or look in the directories where you have installed Wamp)

Comment: The apache error log: AH00422: Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server.